# Redirect to home page after login using “login with google+ account” :Javascript

Tags: google-app-engine

I have follow the steps to create the google+ button and verify the user info. However, I don't know how to redirect to my home page after successfully signed in with my google+ account. Any tips would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the page that we want to redirect in signinCallback(). 
eg:

```
  function signinCallback(authResult) {
   if (authResult['access_token']) {
    // The user is signed in
    var loc = 'index.jsp?GoogleAuthToken=' + authResult['access_token'];
    window.location.href = loc;
    } else if (authResult['error']) {
    // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
     return false;
    }
}
```

This is for redirecting to index page.